# Referencing an Azure AD service principal ID within an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way to get an Azure AD Service Principal ID with an in-built ARM template function? I'm looking for the ARM equivalent of `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "Azure Service Fabric Resource Provider"` and drawing a blank.

Context: I'm following [a tutorial on deploying a Service Fabric managed cluster using an existing load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/how-to-managed-cluster-networking#byolb), and the tutorial requests that you run a powershell command to get the resource provider's service principal ID and then hard-code said ID in the ARM template. This ID is expected to vary by tenant, and the same template will be deployed to multiple tenants.

Comment: Nah you can't get AAD object from ARM. These are different APIs. Best optnio for you is to pass the SP ID as parameter of the ARM template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some Azure resources, you can use the [`reference` template function with the `full` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#remarks-2) to retrieve identity properties.

However, there is no generic way to retrieve a service principal ID within ARM. The `Get-AzADServicePrincipal` powershell cmdlet requires Azure AD graph permissions, which cannot be granted to user assigned MSIs within ARM templates at this time.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Resource Provider Namespace as Microsoft.ServiceFabric

Also, can use in the below way to get the principle id, just need to pass few parameters.

```
[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('uniqueResourceNameBase')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]
```

Reference template as below:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
  "name": "[variables('uniqueResourceNameBase')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "standard"
    },
    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
        "objectId": "[reference(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('uniqueResourceNameBase')), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [],
          "secrets": [
            "get"
          ],
          "certificates": []
        }
      }
    ],
    "enabledForDeployment": false,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('uniqueResourceNameBase'))]"
  ]
}
```

Note: Modify the Resource Provider Namespace and the parameters as per your requirement.